# What kind of bike cleat is this with an arrowhead like logo?

Tags: cleat

What kind of bike cleat is this with an arrowhead like logo?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a Shimano SPD to me

Comment: Do you just want to know which broad type, or exactly who manufactured it? Like Frisbee says, it's an SPD style cleat, but if you want the exact manufacturer of that one all I can say is that it's not Shimano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure Shimano SPD

[Shimano SH56 SPD Cleats Multi Release](http://www.jensonusa.com/!XoRh62J9BoVAjsLEX1zJqg!/Shimano-SH56-SPD-Cleats-Multi-Release)

You need to match to pedals and it looks worn out